# Combining 2 Onedit functions ib 1 script

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I have 2 onEdit scripts as detailed below that conflict. I need to somehow combine the two scrpits in to one.  The fist script autosorts when column 9 in Worksheet1 is edited.
**Question 1: How to make it run if i need the same function aswell but column 11 in Worksheet2?**

The other script inserts a row onEdit, however it does this on all worksheets.
**Question 2: How to restrict it to run when a certain cell is adited ie:Q2 on Worksheets 1 & 2?**

**Question 3: How to combine both scrips into 1 script?**

I am a complete novice at script writing so please make you ansers as simple as possible, thanks

Scripts I have that work separately:

**Script 1 AutoSort**

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  if(sheet.getName()=='Worksheet1') {
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var columnToSortBy = 9;
    var tableRange = "a3:Q999";

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {   
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort({column: 9, ascending: false});

      Browser.msgBox("sort done"); 
    }
  }
}
```

**Script 2 InsertRow**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onEdit() {
    var firstRow = 3;
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
    var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 3, 1, lCol);
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(1, 1);
    newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 3, 1, lCol);
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually make one onEdit function, which will call some other functions one after another:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
  myFunction2();
}

function myFunction1(event) {
  // do something
}

function myFunction2() {
  // do something else
}
```